# Installing Docker in custom docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

This is what I'm trying to do. I have a CICD pipeline I am using to push a docker image into ECR. Within this pipeline I am using a custom Docker image that has the AWSCLIv2, kubectl, and I am trying to also integrate docker within this custom image. I learned this is possible but I am having some blockers. Originally my solution supported the AWSCLI version 1, but I need to have AWSCLIv2. I learned to have v2 of the AWSCLI is a little complex, so that is why I am using Amazon's official image located [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli). Below is my dockerfile. When I try to build my image, I'm getting an error stating there is no docker package available, which is confusing to me because I had installed docker utilizing yum before. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli

ARG KUBECTL_VERSION=1.17.5

RUN yum update -y \
  && yum install docker -y \
  && service docker start

RUN yum install curl -y \
  && curl -sLO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl \
  && mv kubectl /usr/bin/kubectl \
  && chmod +x /usr/bin/kubectl

WORKDIR /apps
```

**Error**

```
Step 3/5 : RUN yum update -y   && yum install docker -y   && service docker start
---> Running in e2473ec54a07
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No packages marked for update
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y   && yum install docker -y   && service docker start' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: If you need docker to build a docker image from a Dockerfile within a container, I suggest taking a look at [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar with a containerized utility I built called `eksutil` ([link](https://github.com/mreferre/eksutils). My image is based off of `amazonlinux:2` which should be the same base image the [aws-cli container uses](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/docker/Dockerfile).

In my dockerfile I can install the docker binary using the following statement:

```
RUN amazon-linux-extras install docker -y
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the docker repo to yum config manager first.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/